# Using distinct in a mongo query in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to use a distinct query for `mongodb` in java. looking at this link it says I can just pass in the field name:

https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#distinct-java.lang.String-

So I have:

```
searchResults = playerCollection.distinct("team");
```

But it says it cannot resolve method distinct(`java.lang.String`)

It seems to think i have to put in another class parameter. But I do not want any subset of the results. I just want all the distinct teams.

Update: How I instantiated the collection:

```
uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://<MongoURI>");
mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
mongoDB = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
playerCollection =  mongoDB.getCollection("players");
```

Comment: Please provide details of how you have defined/instantiated the `playerCollection` object.

Comment: Updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are trying to use is defined for the `DBCollection` class but you are calling it for a `MongoCollection<Document>` class object. Hence the error, because both classes have mathods with the same name but different signatures. The way to use the method you want is by changing the way you instantiate the DB and collection objects.

```
uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://<MongoURI>");
mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);

//http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DB.html
// create a object of the DB class
mongoDB = mongoClient.getDB(uri.getDatabase());

//http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DB.html#getCollection-java.lang.String-
playerCollection =  mongoDB.getCollection("players");

// now that you have a DBCollection object you can use the distinct(String) method
searchResults = playerCollection.distinct("team");
```

Also, the deprecation list for v3.0 (http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/deprecated-list.html#class) does not include the `DB` nor the `DBCollection` class, so you should be fine.

Comment: Cool thanks. Taht sorted it. I thought MongoCollection replaced DBCollection. Cheers for clearing it up

Comment: @discodowney I believe the end game in the long run would be transitioning to template/generic classes, which are considered a better programming pattern/practice.

Answer (score 1):

Please check which driver version you have? I believe `Distinct(<string>`) was in pre 3.0. and now it's gone for good.

Please check

http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#distinct-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Also check type of `mongoDb.getCollection`, it should be `MongoCollection<Document>` not `DbCollection'

> Example:

```
DistinctIterable<Double> documents = playerCollection.distinct("aID", Double.class );

for (Double document : documents) {
    System.out.println(document);
}
```

Where `aID` is your distinct field. Second parameter of `distinct` represents type of `aID`property in MongoDB document.

Hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: Im using 3.2.0. So if I cant do that in this version, then how do I get the distinct values?

Comment: `Distinct(<string>)` is defined for `DBCollection` class which hasn't been deprecated in >v3.0.